# ASP.NET vs Wordpress for Niche Social Network

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, social-networking

I'm looking to build out a niche social network for young girls, nothing too fancy. I'm wondering what would be the best frameworks or languages to build this on. Thanks in advance, all languages or frameworks welcome!

The site is currently on ASP.NET, I feel like there has to be better languages out there for this that would be easier to update and add content to. I'm familiar with Wordpress + Buddypress, but worried about the security & backend. Let me know if more info is needed. Below is a brief feature list:

- Translation capabilities
- Chat
- Profile
- Personal diary (Private)
- Micro-blogging (Public)
- Network Blog w/ Videos
- Friends + Friend request

Few extra questions/notes:

- Is volume of the site a factor on picking the language? If so looking at about 100,000 users.
- I'd like to keep the diary feature private in the back-end as well.
- I'd be hosting an app on my server (I know this is not the best practice just don't want to put it on the app store)

Comment: http://jrmissworld.com/

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to go with ASP.NET. Because **Wordpress are written in PHP, so you can go the route of comparing PHP to .Net development**

**In my opinion, Asp.NET MVC is better than PHP** :

***REASONS:-***

1. **Visual Studio** - Arguably the BEST IDE for web application development. PHP has nothing close to as powerful or helpful.
2. **C#** - Strongly Typed and full of syntactic sugar. The C# Language is one of my favorite to develop in, falling just behind JavaScript. Lambda Expressions are awesome.
3. **LINQ** - PHP doesn't have LINQ or the Entity Framework. I have come to love LINQ so much that I really miss it when using any other language.
4. **SQL Server** - I like SQL Server much more than MySQL and SQL Server Management Studio is the best database IDE I've ever used. .Net plays extremely nice with SQL Server
5. **Razor View Engine** - When I first started programming, I developed something very similar to Razor, but Razor has all the stuff I was trying to do with my own solution. It's like the Razor developers read my mind. It's an awesome syntax and it beats the crap out of the spaghetti code you get with PHP.
6. **Nicely structured applications** - Class Libraries make it much easier to include parts of your framework that you need where you need them. Better than using Includes.